# git push heroku master doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I am following the guide on railstutorial.org. I get this error when I type the command on the title.

Counting objects: 66, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (52/52), done.
Writing objects: 100% (66/66), 86.47 KiB, done.
Total 66 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.0
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
       the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

```
   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * sqlite3-ruby (= 1.3.7)

   You have deleted from the Gemfile:
   * sqlite3-ruby (= 1.2.5)
   FAILED: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler
```

!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:morning-mountain-34.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-mountain-34.git'

then when i type:

$ heroku open

I get a mountain site:http://morning-mountain-34.heroku.com/ which isn't supposed to be the case: should be first_app

Comment: did you rename your application? http://docs.heroku.com/renaming-apps

Comment: No I didn't. I don't even know why its morning-mountain-34 on the tutorial his resulting site was railstutorial.heroku don't see how that happened but the previous tasks were: gem install heroku; heroku keys:add then heroku create----------------------------------- I think I get it. It's just the subdomain name, but if i type that command on the title how do I tell heroku I want my first_app.git on whatever the subdomain is?

Answer (score 3):

found the solution:

first the problem occured possibly because of the so many mistakes I made earlier that I kept on closing the terminal.

so things were probably disabled. like "git init" "git add ." and "git commit -m" I don't really know which one but after doing all those and typing: git push heroku master.

It finally went through and when I type: heroku open. it still opens to morning-mountain-34 but it contains my first app now (which is nothing but its the one on the guide too :))

Comment: The reason it goes to morning-mountain-34 is because you have not assigned a name to the heroku application.  Heroku does this so that your app can live in a unique subdomain that is a memorable, as opposed to something like 121j9j9jk0.  However, if you want it to be secretive, or more memorable, you can change it using: heroku rename new_app_name (see the following link: http://docs.heroku.com/renaming-apps)