# Error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 2

Tags: git, heroku

I am using git repository with heroku server.
I want to commit my changes on heroku server for this i run the command,
git add .
git commit -m 'latest updates'
git push heroku

It give me following error,
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 2
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:deliverydashboard.git'

Please give solution over it.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974257/push-rails-app-to-heroku help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951964/git-push-heroku-master-doesnt-seem-to-work?

Answer (score 0):

This means you have not pushed the master yet.

If you do not already have a repo:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'master'
```

Then create your app on heroku:

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

That will fix the problem.